# How to handling response from Flask backend to run separated Python script?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

**Goal:**

> User inputs a personal token in the frontend which should get passed to a python script in the backend. The python script receives the token, places it correctly in it's code and executes. The scripts output should then be returned to the frontend.

I also want to keep the frontend and backend separated.

I've managed to pass information from the frontend to the backend and then received it back in my Chrome console.

Frontend is running at localhost:5500

Backend is running at localhost:5000

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Insert Token: <input id="token">
      <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
      var token = $("#token").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:5000/token/",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify({"token": token})
      }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      });
  });
});
```

**views.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/token/', methods=['POST'])
def token_input():
  response = request.get_json()
  print(response)
  return jsonify(response)

@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

---

So far, my app gives me:
[so_far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTbf2.png)

---

My guess is:
I have to make a new python script and wrap my script_that_uses_token.py in a function. Then import that function in views.py and somehow use that in the response..?

Comment: Why can't you write it in views.py? However if you split it up in an other py file, it's not that hard to import that file. Anyhow, your code looks good and works for the most part I guess. Can you clarify what exactly your problem is?

Comment: How do I pass the user input into a file.py and place it where it should + execute the file's code? And then return the output back to frontend?

Comment: Should the code come on index.html or an other file? Do you save the value into a db or is it temporary data?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I've got a script which return an output. For the script to be able to execute, it needs a user's token. So I'm trying to pass the token back to my backend and insert it in the script, execute the script and return it back to frontend. I don't use a db at the moment, but I probably should(?). The data is temporary. I just want to display statistics and graphs based on the script's output. No need for saving for later use.

Comment: Don't worry, it isn't that unclear. I ask these extra questions because of the code you posted.What I read from your code is that you send a response to views.py and return that same response to your html/js. I assume that this works because of the console.log(data) returns hello in your console. Anyhow after all this, it's seems to me you already got what you want. Put your logic in token_input() and return the data with return jsonify(yourdata). If any of this in unclear I will post a example with code in an answer.

Comment: Thank you. As you point out, everything was already set up. I just had to complete the logic in my token_input().